# Schedule an event in c#?

Tags: c#, schedule

I have an application that sends text messages through an online service. My users have suggested that I implement a feature of scheduling a message for a future date/time or a recurring message.

Is there a way to do this in c#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to schedule tasks in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752326/best-way-to-schedule-tasks-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) for automating tasks at a particular time in future. You can schedule your message sending at a particular time and Windows will do the rest for you

Comment: Would that make the application wait til a certain time to do something or do I have to implement some kind of command line arguments feature?

Comment: Take a look at this to find out more about how it works or google it for more info http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is a open source job scheduling framework for .Net.

[Tutorial](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: <hint>A link would be nice</hint>