# Asynchronous Take from blocking collection

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm using a `BlockingCollection` to implement a producer/consumer pattern. I have an asynchronous loop that fills the collection with data to be processed which can then at a much later time be accessed by the client. The packets arrive sparsely and I would like the polling to be done without using a blocking call to take.

In essence, I'm looking for something like a `BeginTake` and `EndTake` that does not exist in the blocking collection so that I can make use of the internal thread pool in a callback. It does not have to be a `BlockingCollection` by any means. Anything that does what I need would be great.

This is what I've got now. `_bufferedPackets` is a `BlockingCollection<byte[]>`:

```
public byte[] Read(int timeout)
{
    byte[] result;
    if (_bufferedPackets.IsCompleted)
    {
        throw new Exception("Out of packets");
    }
    _bufferedPackets.TryTake(out result, timeout);      
    return result;
}
```

I'd like this to be something like this, in pseudocode:

```
public void Read(int timeout)
{
    _bufferedPackets.BeginTake(result =>
        {
            var bytes = _bufferedPackets.EndTake(result);
            // Process the bytes, or the resuting timeout
        }, timeout, _bufferedPackets);
}
```

What are my options for this? I do not want to place **any** thread in a waiting state, since there is lots of other IO stuff for it to process, and I would run out of threads pretty quickly.

**Update:** I've rewritten the code in question to use the async process differently, essentially swapping callbacks based on if there is a waiting request within the timeout limit. This works fine, but still it would be awesome if there was a way to do this without resorting to timers and swapping lambdas around which potentially causes race conditions and is hard to write (and understand). I have  solved this also with an own implementation of an async queue, but it would still be awesome if there was a more standard and well tested option.

Comment: At the moment, I think no collection of TPL provide asynchronous methods except ObservableCollection to UI. What do you think ?

Comment: You could wrap this in a `Task<byte[]> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<byte[]>(() => { // Your Code returning byte[] });` however this is not elligent and there must be a better way...

Comment: Wrapping in a task will consume a task that will be locked in a wait handle. Since there are many tasks going on that will occupy a task forever which will make me run out of tasks in the pool unfortunately.

Comment: @Dervall If you're afraid you will reach the maximum number of threads in the pool, then I think there's something wrong with your design. Maybe `BlockingCollection.TakeFromAny()` could be useful?

Comment: Can't use .Net 4.5. Oh how I wish I could. The application is heavily IO-bound and reactive based on inputs from stream. This is a detached stream that buffers on the backside, and responds to polls by returning packages one by one to the polling client. The client typically either has a packet waiting, or it might arrive within the allotted timeout. Since there might be a LOT of these polling clients to hog a thread in a blocking wait will be unacceptable in the long run. The pool needs to be available for more asynchronous IO action.

Comment: Stephen Toub describes writing a producer/producer queue here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/04/12/blocking-queues.aspx but I think it would be trivial to write a BeginDequeue or a DequeueAsync...

Comment: you might want to take a look at reactive extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there doesn't look to be a built in option for this, I went out and tried to do my best to make what I wanted as an experiment. Turns out there is a lot of cruft to do in order to make this work roughly as other users of the old async pattern.

```
public class AsyncQueue<T>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<T> queue;
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<DequeueAsyncResult> dequeueQueue; 

    private class DequeueAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
    {
        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
        public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle { get; set; }
        public object AsyncState { get; set; }
        public bool CompletedSynchronously { get; set; }
        public T Result { get; set; }

        public AsyncCallback Callback { get; set; }
    }

    public AsyncQueue()
    {
        dequeueQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<DequeueAsyncResult>();
        queue = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        DequeueAsyncResult asyncResult;
        while  (dequeueQueue.TryDequeue(out asyncResult))
        {
            if (!asyncResult.IsCompleted)
            {
                asyncResult.IsCompleted = true;
                asyncResult.Result = item;

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
                {
                    if (asyncResult.Callback != null)
                    {
                        asyncResult.Callback(asyncResult);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((EventWaitHandle) asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle).Set();
                    }
                });
                return;
            }
        }
        queue.Enqueue(item);
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginDequeue(int timeout, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        T result;
        if (queue.TryDequeue(out result))
        {
            var dequeueAsyncResult = new DequeueAsyncResult
            {
                IsCompleted = true, 
                AsyncWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.ManualReset), 
                AsyncState = state, 
                CompletedSynchronously = true, 
                Result = result
            };
            if (null != callback)
            {
                callback(dequeueAsyncResult);
            }
            return dequeueAsyncResult;
        }

        var pendingResult = new DequeueAsyncResult
        {
            AsyncState = state, 
            IsCompleted = false, 
            AsyncWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset), 
            CompletedSynchronously = false,
            Callback = callback
        };
        dequeueQueue.Enqueue(pendingResult);
        Timer t = null;
        t = new Timer(_ =>
        {
            if (!pendingResult.IsCompleted)
            {
                pendingResult.IsCompleted = true;
                if (null != callback)
                {
                    callback(pendingResult);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((EventWaitHandle)pendingResult.AsyncWaitHandle).Set();
                }
            }
            t.Dispose();
        }, new object(), timeout, Timeout.Infinite);

        return pendingResult;
    }

    public T EndDequeue(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var dequeueResult = (DequeueAsyncResult) result;
        return dequeueResult.Result;
    }
}
```

I'm not too sure about the synchronization of the `IsComplete` property, and I'm not too hot on how the `dequeueQueue` only gets cleaned up on subsequent `Enqueue` calls. I'm not sure when is the correct time to signal the wait handles either but this is the best solution that I've got so far.

Please do not consider this production quality code by any means. I just wanted to show the general gist of how I got around to keeping all threads spinning without waiting locks. I'm sure this is full of all kinds of edge cases and bugs but it fulfills the requirements and I wanted to give something back to people who comes across the question.

Comment: I do not completely do understand your threading model. You do access in EndDequeue the Result regardless if the callback has completed or timed out. If you loop over the IsCompleted property until you get an answer you are still blocking a thread.

Comment: It won't block since its running on a timer, which will not start a thread but only queue tasks on the pool. Enddequeue is called on timeouts as well, result would be default in those cases.

Comment: I mean who is calling EndDequeue? The Begin/End pattern ensures that you can spawn off work but at some point you need to call the corresponding End method. What you currently do is to register callbacks and call them during the Enqueue method and wait a little bit via the timer if in the meantime some data did arrive. You can do it without timers by simply have an observer queue where you upon Enqueue store their enqueue time. When data arrives you dequeue all too old observer and skip them and call the callback which has not expired yet.

Comment: @AloisKraus Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you but EndDequeue should be called from the callback, or after the waithandle exposed in the IAsyncResult has been signalled. I would want the callback to be called on timeout regardless if data has arrived. Using an observer queue like that would not ensure that the callback becomes called in the timeout scenario, so only the calls that actually received data would have their callbacks called.

Comment: The way you did implement the reading strategey you still can suffer threadpool exhaustion if many observers time out at the same time (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581/how-scalable-is-system-threading-timer). You could use one global timer which does check the pending IAsyncResults at once from time to time which would be more safe in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your situation, but can't you use a non-blocking collection?

I created this example to illustrate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncTakeFromBlockingCollection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

            var producer1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue("=======");
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
            });

            var producer2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue("*******");
                    Thread.Sleep(3);
                }
            });

            CreateConsumerTask("One  ", 3, queue);
            CreateConsumerTask("Two  ", 4, queue);
            CreateConsumerTask("Three", 7, queue);

            producer1.Wait();
            producer2.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("  Producers Finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void CreateConsumerTask(string taskName, int sleepTime, ConcurrentQueue<string> queue)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    string result;
                    if (queue.TryDequeue(out result))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("  {0} consumed {1}", taskName, result);
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the program's output

[image]

I believe the BlockingCollection is intended to wrap a concurrent collection and provide a mechanism to allow multiple consumers to block; waiting for producers. This usage appears to be contrary to your requirements.

I found this [article about the BlockingCollection class](http://www.codethinked.com/blockingcollection-and-iproducerconsumercollection) to be helpful.

Comment: I can't really do that unfortunately. There are many separate queues that gets filled up very sparsely upon IO completions. There can potentially be thousands of these. These are then only consumed from when another IO-event happens, which runs in an IO-completion callback and thus cannot block. In essence there are infrequent producers and consumers, all running on IO-completion. The consumer needs to know if the collection has had items added within a given timeout without placing itself in a blocking call.

Comment: How are the consumers mapped to queues? One consumer for each queue? Do consumers iterate through the queues looking for products?

Comment: Consumers arrive asynchronously on IO callbacks and are required to pull things out of the collection, or wait a set period of time before giving up if the collection is not filled with data during that time. No iteration, it's basically a queue

Comment: Sorry; I was attempting to ask if the consumers iterate through the thousands of queues, not the queues themselves. Thanks for the further insight.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `BlockingCollection<T>` can't do this, you'd have to roll your own.  I came up with this:

```
class NotifyingCollection<T>
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<Action<T>> _subscribers = new ConcurrentQueue<Action<T>>();
    private ConcurrentQueue<T> _overflow = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();

    private object _lock = new object();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _overflow.Enqueue(item);
        Dispatch();
    }

    private void Dispatch()
    {
        // this lock is needed since we need to atomically dequeue from both queues...
        lock (_lock)
        {
            while (_overflow.Count > 0 && _subscribers.Count > 0)
            {
                Action<T> callback;
                T item;

                var r1 = _overflow.TryDequeue(out item);
                var r2 = _subscribers.TryDequeue(out callback);

                Debug.Assert(r1 && r2);
                callback(item);
                // or, optionally so that the caller thread's doesn't take too long ...
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => callback(item));
                // but you'll have to consider how exceptions will be handled.
            }
        }
    }

    public void TakeAsync(Action<T> callback)
    {
        _subscribers.Enqueue(callback);
        Dispatch();
    }
}
```

I've used the thread which calls `TakeAsync()` or `Add()` to serve as the callback thread.  When you call `Add()` or `TakeAsync()` it will attempt to dispatch all the queued-up items to the queued-up callbacks.  This way there's no thread created that just sits there sleeping, waiting to be signalled.

That lock is kind of ugly, but you'll be able to enqueue and subscribe on multiple threads without locking.  I couldn't figure out a way to do the equivalent of *only dequeue one if there's something available on the other queue* without using that lock.

*Note: I only tested this minimally, with a few threads.*

Comment: Well, yes. The only problem is that you'll create a locked thread using your approach which would be dangerous considering a very high load. The `TryTake` call blocks. In a situation where you have thousands of these calls you'd run out of threads in the task thread pool and lock your application.

Comment: Ah! you wanted no blocking threads altogether; I thought you had just wanted to ensure the calling thread wouldn't get blocked.  I get it now.