# System.Threading.Timer to handle async timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

Lets say I have a loop and Im uploading some files somewhere. If I dont have a connection I just reconnect again. If I tried to connect x times I want to wait. For this wait time I could use a Timer. But because the application is doing other stuff too, it should not be sync - I want this as async. Is it a good idea to create a `System.Threading.Timer` and count this down? And then I could add something like `if (Timer done) { connect again and upload }` Any suggestions?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581/how-scalable-is-system-threading-timer

Comment: If this code is not already running on a worker thread then it probably should.  Waiting is now not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application is doing other things why is it OK to block on the uploads but not block on the wait.  Do it all a BackGroundWorker and ProgressChanged to show how many files are complete.

[BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)